# OCaml pattern reconstruction with let

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, let

So I've noticed it is possible to reconstruct any patterns with "let" expressions, even when it's a function declaration.

It can be pretty useful in cases like:

```ml
let [c; f; x] = map (fun _ -> scanf " %f" id) (1--3) in ...
```

However, this emits a warning because the pattern isn't exhaustive: indeed, it could fail. But in my case, that is exactly the intended behavior when the pattern doesn't match (and my assertion about the input is wrong): the statement should fail (and the failure could possibly be caught at some point up the stack).

I don't like having those warnings (and I don't want to globally turn them off!) so I'm forced to fall back on the very cumbersome (and no safer):

```ml
let c, f, x = match (map (fun _ -> scanf " %f" id) (1--3)) with
| [c; f; x] -> c, f, x
| _ -> failwith "wrong assertion"
in ...
```

**Isn't there a way to get the succinct syntax of the first alternative without the scary warnings?** Or another construct that would involve less typing than a full-blown match statement?

Note: I think it would also be nice to be able to specify a function only takes a given alternative of a sum type without emitting a warning at the declaration site. It would be for the caller to ensure he uses the right argument, or he would get a warning...

```ml
type ast = Id of string | Var of string * int
let foo (Var(s,n)) = ...

foo (Var("bar", 42)) (* ok *)
foo (Id "bar")       (* warning; or even error *)
```

(This is because to me having a signature like "foo s n" doesn't make it clear foo is intended to be used with the data of a Var-constructed ast.)

Comment: You could define `let foo (s, n) = ...`, and it's up to the caller to get the `(s, n)` from an `ast` - if possible.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the problem. For example, what if another alternative (or even type) has the same signature?

Comment: You probably want to selectively turn off the warning, not any sort of type-level guarantee. Your best bet is to write a syntax extension that transforms a `let`-derived form to pattern matching with a `failwith` branch.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds more like what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could use variant types:

```
type ast = [`Id of string | `Var of string * int]

let foo (`Var (s, n)) = (s, n)
(* val foo : [< `Var of 'a * 'b ] -> 'a * 'b *)

foo (`Var("bar", 42)) (* : string * int = ("bar", 42) *)
foo (`Id "bar") (* Error: This expression has type [> `Id of string ] *)
```

Comment: Right, but it's a pity one cannot call foo as you defined it using variants with an object from a sum type :/

Comment: @LP_ What you're asking is truly impossible, without dependent types. The closest you could get is using variant types - but the OCaml type system limits you to how much you can use them. The type of `Var ("foo", 42)` really is `ast`, and no static analysis in the OCaml type checker would dare question it.